# How to give a value a specific length

Tags: mysql, char, varchar, string-length

I currently have a value for a code which is a varchar(45), but I want this code to only be exactly 5 characters long, which query with a constraint should I write to do this? I have tried what I have done down here, but it didn't work

```
ALTER TABLE `bigfivesafari`.`accommodatie` 
ADD INDEX `accommodatiecode` (`accommodatiecode`(5) ASC) VISIBLE;
```

Comment: Not with you, are you saying you have a table column defined as varchar(45) which you want to limit to exactly 5 characters?

Comment: Such a constraint belongs in the column definition, not the `INDEX`.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, but thankfully it has been fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in MySQL 8.0.27:

```
mysql> create table accommodatie ( accommodatiecode varchar(45) 
          check (accommodatiecode regexp '^....[[:digit:]]$'));

mysql> insert into accommodatie set accommodatiecode = 'abc';
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'accommodatie_chk_1' is violated.

mysql> insert into accommodatie set accommodatiecode = 'abcde';
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'accommodatie_chk_1' is violated.

mysql> insert into accommodatie set accommodatiecode = 'abcd5';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```